# data being pulled in from mysql but cant pass it to html via ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am using a php file to pull data from a mysql database and then pushing it through to a html page using Ajax:

the data is being pulled in correctly and it looks to be pushed through as it shows in the network tab (response) but when i look in the console log there is nothing showing any ideas why

php

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$servername = "test:3306";
$username = "test";
$password = "test!";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
#   header('Content-Type: applicaton/json');


$sql = "SELECT beacon,TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(max(`time`),min(`time`)), '%i.%s') 
AS `delivery_avg` 
FROM `test`.`test` 
where date = CURDATE()
and time > now() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE
group by beacon ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$sql2 = 'SELECT 
* 
FROM
(SELECT
 beacon,location,date,
COUNT(location) AS counter 
FROM `test`.`test`
WHERE `date` = CURDATE() and `time` > NOW() - interval 40 second
GROUP BY beacon) AS SubQueryTable
ORDER BY SubQueryTable.counter DESC;';
$result = $conn->query($sql2);


$result = mysqli_query($conn ,  $sql);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);

$result2 = mysqli_query($conn ,  $sql2);
$rows2 = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
  $rows2[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows2);

$conn->close();
?>
```

html

```
 <script>    
 $(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr>').appendTo("#zoning tbody");
        for (var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
            $(`<td class='${i * 10 + j}'>${i * 10 + j}</td>`).appendTo(row);
        }
    }

    $.get('php/test.php', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var row;
        response.forEach(function(item, index) {
            console.log(item.delivery_avg,item.beacon,item.location);
            $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
        });
    });


        function updateTable() {
        //console.log('function called');
        $('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
        $.get('php/test.php', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(item, index) {
                console.log(item.delivery_avg,item.beacon,item.location);
                //$('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
        $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css('background-color', item.location).toggleClass('coloured');
        if (item.delivery_avg <= 10.00) {
             return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'lime', 'border-width':'thick'}).toggleClass('coloured');
        } else if (item.delivery_avg>= 10.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 20.00) {
             return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'orange', 'border-width':'thick','background-color':item.location}).toggleClass('coloured');
        } else if (item.delivery_avg>= 20.01 && item.delivery_avg <= 30.00) {
             return $(`td.${item.beacon}`).css({'border-color':'pink', 'border-width':'thick','background-color':item.location}).toggleClass('coloured');

        }
            });
        });
}
    var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 2000);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Echoing __two valid__ json strings makes json __invalid__.

Comment: is there a way around this? i tried to run the 2 queries as one but couldnt get it to work due to the time intervals

Comment: Put both arrays into one outer array and return `json_encode`d outer array.

Comment: sorry that is all foreign to me haha is it possible that you could link me to an example?

Comment: Example of what? Putting data in arrays?

Comment: yes how could i but both arrays into one outer array?

Comment: `$array[] = $another_array`. Please, refer to php basics if you don't know how to work with arrays.